# raco setup: directory does not exist for collection

Tags: racket

When I try to install a package through raco, I get a strange error message:

```
raco setup: directory: #<path:/Users/ben/code/racket/benchmark/tr-pfds/pfds> does not exist for collection: "pfds"
```

Even stranger, running `raco pkg show` doesn't show anything about this "pfds" collection:

```
Installation-wide:
 Package              Checksum                                     Source
 main-distribution    f07e2d4bf2708c1085be38eca18aa9eb6755e547    (catalog main-distribution)
 racket-lib           41c7b3221006758c5a840a18dcc0d265632f14c2    (catalog racket-lib)
 [178 auto-installed packages not shown]
User-specific for installation "6.1":
 Package            Checksum                                    Source
 benchmark          1237b50804bb42bd242ba7b3eb6e2b98794b40ee    (catalog benchmark)
 feature-profile    109e89701839a6d2fed9d1713aef8d21cc8b54d4    (catalog feature-profile)
 quickcheck         1afac87825c5da8b35b327f5df3f1f9e1bf3cb9d    (catalog quickcheck)
 rackunit-chk       9c6e9c346c0e83bd3bb8dd16e321a2fa3e02b42e    (catalog rackunit-chk)
```

Another thing I tried was just removing the "pfds" collection, but that didn't go well either:

```
raco6.1 pkg remove pfds
Removing pfds
raco6.1 pkg remove: package not currently installed
  package: pfds
  current scope: user
```

But in retrospect this error makes sense to me, because the directory `/Users/ben/code/racket/benchmark/tr-pfds/pfds` doesn't exist on my machine. I deleted it a few weeks ago.

Does anyone know what's going on?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Have you used `raco link` in the past? You can sometimes see this error message if you have `raco link`ed a directory that you have since deleted.

There are three things you can try:

1. Run `raco link --repair`. This should ideally repair your installation by removing all dead links.
2. Run `raco link -r pkfds`, this should remove your `pfds` link.
3. Check your `links.rktd` file, which can be found in:

   - (Linux) `~/.racket/<version>/links.rktd`
   - (OS X) `~/Library/Racket/<version>/links.rktd`
   - (Windows) `C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Roaming\Racket\<version>\links.rktd`

In the file, you may see a link to `pfds`, which is causing the issue.

Once the link is removed, `raco setup` should work normally again.

(As an addendum, it might be interesting to note that [`raco link` has an API call from within Racket](http://docs.racket-lang.org/raco/link.html#%28def._%28%28lib._setup%2Flink..rkt%29._links%29%29).)

Comment: Thanks! Removing the file from `links.rktd` fixed me.